# How to find out submodules call in a module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, module

I want to list out all the function call including submodule calls in a list. In my case it is os_list for os module. I want to store calls of os.path module calls along with this.For identification of function call I am using "__call", What is used for identifying the module.

```
for name in dir(os):
    attr = getattr(os, name)
    if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
        os_list.append(name)
```

Comment: Make it a little more clear. You're trying to find all `os` functions, that are used in a current or in a target module?

Answer (score 2):

Note: other objects might have a *__call__* method (*e.g.* classes). 
You can check an object type using [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - isinstance(object, classinfo)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance). For modules, the *classinfo* argument should be [[Python.Docs]: class types.ModuleType(name, doc=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.ModuleType):

```py
isinstance(attr, types.ModuleType)
```

While we are on the subject, you could do the same for functions. So, your code would look like:

```py
from types import BuiltinFunctionType, FunctionType, ModuleType

# ...

os_list = []
for name in dir(os):
    attr = getattr(os, name)
    if isinstance(attr, (BuiltinFunctionType, FunctionType, ModuleType)):
        os_list.append(name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?